# What does the semantic entailment relation mean (M |= A)?

Tags: logic

I read many acticles about it. They described it as :

> In logics, meaning is often described by a satisfaction relation
>
> M |= A
>
> that describes when a situation M satisfies a formula A.

So, I also searched some examples. I found the examples following :

> True |= False = false
>
> False |= True = true

I don't understand at all. What does it mean in these cases?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on one of the math sites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(assuming that you talk about propositional logic (it is similar for other logics such as pred. logic))

for two formulas A and B:

```
A |= B 
"B evaluates to true under all evaluations that evaluate A to true"
```

for a set of formulas M and a formula B:

```
M |= B
"for every evaluation: B evaluates to true if only all elements of M
 evaluate to true"
```

coming to your examples:

```
true |= false 
is incorrect since evaluations exist


false |= A
is correct for any formula A, since 'false' is never evaluated to 'true'
under any evaluation
```

rgrds.

Comment: Thanks @olodnad, but I have some questions. 
Why false := A is correct. "for every  evaluation : A evaluates to true if only all elements of false evaluate to true"
But now, the left part false is equal to false. So, why it's correct?

Comment: to see that "false |= A" we have to convince ourselves that whenever an evaluation evaluates 'false' to 'true' then it also evaluates 'A' to true. However, since no evaluation ever evaluates 'false' to true at all, it is save to say that every evaluation that evaluates 'false' to 'true' will also avaluate 'A' to 'true'.

Comment: also note that 'false' is a formula, not a set of formulas, therefore you need to apply the first definition of '|=' instead of the second one (as implied by your comment).